# I need to calculate sum on multiple fields in Google Datastore (NoSQL database)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, database, nosql

we are building a recommender, comparing user interests with the characteristics of places. For example. Does the user like 'outdoor' and does the place store a high value for 'outdoor' then the place is recommended.

My Google Datastore document structure is

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Netherlands", "outdoor": 4, "painting":5, "history": 6, "drink"; 7, "love": 8 }
```

What I want to make is to calculate sum on multiple fields.

With MongoDB, I can implement it like this.

```
db.characteristics.aggregate(
   [
     { $project: { name: 1, score: { $add: [ "$outdoor", "$love" ] } }}
   ]
)
```

And the output will be

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Netherlands", "score" : 12 }
```

I can make this easily with MongoDB query but I have no idea how to make this with google datastore API.

So if anyone has experience with my problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a natively supported feature (virtual fields) of the query engine. You'd just have to write the code that manually aggregated the fields after reading the entity.

If you are using App Engine Standard and the Python NDB client library, you can use [ComputedProperties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#computed) in your model, but keep in mind this is essentially just a client-side helper function.